# Pardot - engagement history view

Tags: pardot

When I view engagement history for a Lead view in Salesforce, I see moments such as Email Open: Email Asset Name. My expectation is that clicking on the email asset name (red arrow below) would allow me to preview that particular email asset, either in the same or a new window:

[image]

However, the actual behavior is that it opens up in pi.pardot.com. That's no good because then I have to log in again and then context switch and re-orient, etc. just a lot of clicking overhead.

This is a poor user experience, as the engagement history should ideally be useful to a salesperson and a salesperson shouldn't have to go hunting around just to see what the relevant email asset was if they just clicked on it.

Does anyone know if this is by design, or customizable?

Appreciate any pointers, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have SSO implemented between SF and Pardot (aka "new" Pardot/SF integration) via Pardot Lightning app?

Comment: Yes @identigral we do have that implemented so the 2 shake hands. So this happens in spite of that.